# Compile-to-JavaScript option that uses a Decimal library instead of IEEE 754 math?

Tags: javascript, typescript, decimal, ieee-754

In JavaScript `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` and [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) explains why because of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_formats) math.  I am working with applications in the finance/accounting domain and want a way to make `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3`

Therefore, I am looking for a solution that can take code similar to the below example with type annotations for Decimal (using the [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) syntax).

```
var a:Decimal, b:Decimal, c:Decimal;

a = 0.1;
b = 0.2;

c = a + b;
```

The compile/macro expansion process could output this code which uses a JavaScript Decimal library (e.g. [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)), so c = `0.3` and not `0.30000000000000004`

```
var a, b, c;

a = new Decimal(0.1);
b = new Decimal(0.2);

c = a.plus(b);
```

---

Mozilla [sweet.js](http://sweetjs.org/) macros seems to support [custom operators](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#custom-operators) which "let you define your own operators or override the built-in operators."

**Question:** Is this behavior possible with sweet.js?  Are there any similar examples?

---

TypeScript transpiles source code and this concept has been asked about before with TypeScript:

- [Implement Operator overloading in TypeScript...](https://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397848)
- [Suggestion: int type #195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/195)

**Question:** Can the TypeScript compiler be extended to support this use case?  Would this be appropriate for a feature request?

---

Additionally, a [blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/bparadie/2011/11/22/0-2-0-1-0-30000000000000004/) in a series about cross-compiling ActionScript to JavaScript concluded they wanted "same wrong result in ActionScript and JavaScript" for consistency reasons, but that did not assume additional type annotations.

**Question:** Are there other strategies or compile-to-JavaScript options to achieve this goal?

Comment: confused why this was voted as off-topic, so edited question to be more explicit?  open to suggestions to edits

Comment: haven't you considered using `decimal.js` explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a compile-to-JavaScript solution that does this today

One worth mentioning that does support operator overriding and does have *optional* type annotations is google's Dart : https://www.dartlang.org/

Operator overriding : https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/#operators 
Optional Types : https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could do all the maths using a separate math library. For example [math.js](http://mathjs.org) comes with an expression parser and supports bignumbers (powered by [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)):

```
math.config({number: 'bignumber'});

// using a parser to manage variables for you in an internal scope:
var parser = math.parser();
parser.eval('a = 0.1');   // BigNumber, 0.1
parser.eval('b = 0.2');   // BigNumber, 0.2
parser.eval('c = a + b'); // BigNumber, 0.3

// or without a parser: 
var scope = {};
math.eval('a = 0.1', scope);   // BigNumber, 0.1
math.eval('b = 0.2', scope);   // BigNumber, 0.2
math.eval('c = a + b', scope); // BigNumber, 0.3
// scope now contains properties a, b, and c
```

I don't know if this would be feasible and handy for your application, but at least that would allow you to write your equations in "readable" expressions.